# Xen 6.2 - NIC bonding - LACP or active/active?

Tags: xenserver, nic, bonding

I have 3 XenServer 6.2 machines with 4x 1Gb NICs. Would I be better served by:

1. putting these in an LACP bond at the switch
2. putting these in an active/active at the xen server
3. leaving them separated?

Comment: You did the right thing, leaving the management interface on its own physical port.  Seems that you can only join a machine to a pool if it has no bonds configured, and if the pool has a bond that will immediately become the network configuration on the new pool guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW: based on [this](http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/27046-102-666250/XS-design-network_advanced.pdf) document I'm going to configure 1 NIC as the management interface and make the other 3 active/active. Each VM will get (re)assigned to the bonded NIC.

Comment: This worked out well. One caveat is that when you add the additional NIC(becomes ETH1) and remove the old one(ETH0) you'll need to move it to ETH0 before you reboot or networking won't start.